# combine overlapping data ranges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

Given a Pandas dataframe `df1`

```
  column_name  id column_value   from_date     to_date
0       score   8            B  2021-01-01  2021-01-04
1       score   8           B+  2021-01-05  2021-01-10
2       score   9            Z  2021-01-01  2021-01-10
```

and another `df2`

```
  column_name  id      column_value   from_date     to_date
0       score   8  AAAAAAA-override  2021-01-03  2021-01-07
1       score   9       B+-override  2021-01-08  2021-01-10
```

I want to create a new dataframe that groupby `id` and combine overlapping date ranges between `df1` and `df2`. In case of overlapping I will take the `column_value` of df2.

The final result is `df`:

```
       from_date    to_date  id      column_value
index                                            
1     2021-01-01 2021-01-02   8                 B
2     2021-01-03 2021-01-07   8  AAAAAAA-override
3     2021-01-08 2021-01-10   8                B+
4     2021-01-01 2021-01-07   9                Z
5     2021-01-08 2021-01-10   9       B+-override
```

My solution at the moment is very slow because I add every dates from `from_date` to `to_date`, then I overlap the two dataframes and `groupby` the new date and take the value from `df2`. Then I compact the result back to a from and a to.

This doesn't scale for the type of data that we have has we can have more than 100k ids and the range of dates are quite wide: from 1900-01-01 to today.

Anyone can think of a more scalable solution? maybe using `IntervalIndex` or shall I just use normal python?

Comment: Will "overlapping date ranges" be identical? I am not sure I understand your question properly

Comment: Will all id's both be present in ```df1``` and ```df2```?

Comment: id's will be both in df1 and df2 as a mean to correlate them. In the final df dates cannot overlaps (for the same id) but they are contiguous. For example in `df2` the row:
`0       score   8  AAAAAAA-override  2021-01-03  2021-01-07`
is overlapping with the first and second row in `df1`. 
The final result should be contiguous dates as in rows 1,2 and 3 in `df`. Note that the second row has the value from `df2`

Answer (score 1):

- looking at this,  overrides are always in you result DF.
- where override is taken, overlapping none-override **to_date** is modified to be one day before **from_date** of override
- overlapping **from_date** is modified to be one day after override **to_date**
- this can then be done in a concatenated DF where you know the source of the row, looking for previous row or next row being an override, grouped by **id**
- have shown as new columns just for transparency,  clearly `assign()` can be required column,  plus the **O** column can be dropped

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  column_name  id column_value   from_date     to_date
0       score   8            B  2021-01-01  2021-01-04
1       score   8           B+  2021-01-05  2021-01-10
2       score   9            Z  2021-01-01  2021-01-10"""), sep="\s+")
df1.from_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.from_date)
df1.to_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.to_date)

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  column_name  id      column_value   from_date     to_date
0       score   8  AAAAAAA-override  2021-01-03  2021-01-07
1       score   9       B+-override  2021-01-08  2021-01-10"""), sep="\s+")
df2.from_date = pd.to_datetime(df2.from_date)
df2.to_date = pd.to_datetime(df2.to_date)

df3 = pd.concat([df1.assign(O=False),df2.assign(O=True)]).sort_values(["id","from_date","to_date"])
df3 = df3.groupby(["id"]).apply(lambda dfa: dfa.assign(
    new_from_date=np.where(~dfa.O & dfa.O.shift(),
                           dfa.to_date.shift()+pd.Timedelta(days=1),
                           dfa.from_date),
    new_to_date=np.where(~dfa.O & dfa.O.shift(-1),
                         dfa.from_date.shift(-1)-pd.Timedelta(days=1),
                         dfa.to_date),

)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### output

|  | column_name | id | column_value | from_date | to_date | O | new_from_date | new_to_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | score | 8 | B | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | False | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 1 | score | 8 | AAAAAAA-override | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | True | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2 | score | 8 | B+ | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | False | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 |
| 3 | score | 9 | Z | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | False | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 4 | score | 9 | B+-override | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | True | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 |

Comment: Unfortunately the implementation does not cover the case where the range of a row in the overrides `df2` is within the range of a row in `df1`. For example:

df1: `0       score   8            B  2020-01-01  2021-01-01`
and
df2:  `0       score   8        AAAAAAA-override   2020-06-01  2020-06-10`.

what I am expecting are three rows:
 `0       score   8        B   2020-01-01  2021-05-31`.
 `0       score   8        AAAAAAA-override   2020-06-01  2021-06-10`.
 `0       score   8        B   2020-06-11  2021-01-01`.